# Is there a way to connect Room database with MySql workbench?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, android-room

I am working on an android project and we have a server side database on MySql workbench and are using Room for our local database in Android Studio. Is there a way to connect/sync the two?

Thank you.

Comment: Most things can be done in software, probably by writing code to get it done. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

Well...

Im pretty sure room is SQLite based while MySql workbench is obviously MySQL based...
so there is that. afaik there is possibility to somehow export from MySQL to SQLite, but that no way means you can use it to browse MySQL database.

It is possible to write your own implimation to MySQL workbench, but what you are looking for is not readily available, to my knowlage.